# How to fit legend on graphs

Tags: r

I have the following code and can't figure out how to fit the legend on, without it overlapping with the graph. Any ideas?

```
slices <- c(34, 9, 13, 7, 6, 2, 29 )
    colors <-c("dodgerblue4", "steelblue3","slategray3", "yellow", 
           "yellowgreen", "brown", "pink", "beige")
    lbls <- c("Making a Robot", "Solar Oven", "Bottle Rocket Challenge", 
          "How to Clean Water","Marstronaut", "Cargo Drop", "Other")
    lblsp <- c("34%", "9%", "13%", "7%", "6%", "2%", "29%")
    par(mar=c(0, 10, 1, 1))
    pie(slices, labels = lblsp, col = colors, border = F)
    legend("topright", legend=lbls,fill=colors, bty='n')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to adjust the `radius` of `pie` :

```
slices <- c(34, 9, 13, 7, 6, 2, 29 )
colors <-c("dodgerblue4", "steelblue3","slategray3", "yellow", 
           "yellowgreen", "brown", "pink", "beige")
lbls <- c("Making a Robot", "Solar Oven", "Bottle Rocket Challenge", 
          "How to Clean Water","Marstronaut", "Cargo Drop", "Other")
lblsp <- c("34%", "9%", "13%", "7%", "6%", "2%", "29%")
par(mar=c(0, 10, 1, 1))
pie(slices, labels = lblsp, col = colors, border = F, radius = 0.45)
legend("topright", legend=lbls,fill=colors, bty='o')
```

[image]

---

You can also put the legends in two columns using the `ncol` parameter in `legend`.

```
pie(slices, labels = lblsp, col = colors, border = F, radius = 0.6)
legend("topright", legend=lbls,fill=colors, bty='o', ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use x, y inputs to position the legend, or you can use "topright" as you did, with an inset input.